CORS with Istio and oauth2-proxy
I have added corsPolicy on my Istio Virtual Service route so that the response contains the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when the request contains an Origin header. It works well.
I have added oauth2-proxy using an AuthorizationPolicy with CUSTOM action. Now the response doesn't contain the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header anymore, even after successful authentication.
Is there something to do in oauth2-proxy or envoyExtAuthzHttp configuration to fix CORS support ?

I finally fixed it by adding the following EnvoyFilter:
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: cors-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.http.cors
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors"

